# undefined method `hstore' for Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm following along with Ryan Bates' preview of Rails 4 in episode 400 of Railscasts http://railscasts.com/episodes/400-what-s-new-in-rails-4. He sets up the application to use postgres (which I have installed) with a demonstration of hstore. He creates a scaffold like this

```
rails g scaffold article name content:text published_on:date tags properties:hstore
```

and in the migration does this

```
execute "create extension hstore"
create_table :articles do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.text :content
  t.date :published_on
  t.string :tags, array: true
  t.hstore :properties
  t.timestamps
end
```

However, when I ran this migration I got an undefined method 'hstore' error. I then went into my test database and created the hstore extension as you see below (rather than in the migration file as Ryan did)

```
psql rails4test2_development
psql (9.2.3)
Type "help" for help.

rails4test2_development=# CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
```

But I got the same error when I ran the migration.

```
undefined method `hstore' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::TableDefinition:0x007fa7ee7a9138>/Users/me/Sites/rails4test2/db/migrate/20130511204911_create_articles.rb:9:in `block in change'
/Users/me/Sites/rails4test2/db/migrate/20130511204911_create_articles.rb:4:in `change'
```

Can anyone help me understand why this isn't working for me?

Comment: @GoGoGarrett, I'm not completely sure on the type of answer you are expecting; A quick search for `hstore` column method or type in the following two files taken from [Rails 3.2.19](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.19/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb) and [Rails 4.2.0beta1](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.0.beta1/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_definitions.rb) shows that the method is undefined in latest Rails 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that, even though I installed Rails 4 gem,  the application was using Rails 3.2 still, which doesn't support `hstore` natively.

Comment: For others who may have this same error but are using rails 4: Another possible way to get this same error when using psql cli to CREATE EXTENSION hstore; rather than a migration, is to forget to redo this command after dropping and re-creating the db.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is a problem with many potential causes. For us, the cause was the seamless_database_pool gem.

https://github.com/bdurand/seamless_database_pool/issues/17